# How to check if 2 dicts are equal except some fields?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

There are two dicts: old and updated. I wanna to check if they are equal, except `status`, `latitude` and `longitude` keys.

```
assert old_dict['status'] != updated_dict['status']
assert old_dict['latitude'] != updated_dict['latitude']
assert old_dict['longitude'] != updated_dict['longitude']

for field in ('status', 'latitude', 'longitude'):
    updated_dict.pop(field)
    old_dict.pop(field)

assert old_dict == updated_dict
```

What is the more pythonic way to do this?

Comment: Does the status (and lat./lon.) _have to_ differ as implied in your code?

Comment: Do you want to check that excepted keys are different too (eg. status), or are your initial asserts just to demonstrate that the dicts would have otherwise been considered unequal? That is, given two identical dicts, would you like the result of the comparison to be false, because the values for the excepted keys were equal.

Comment: Are you only interested in a more Pythonic solution, or are you also interested in efficiency/speed?

Comment: @norok2 both, could you please provide solution for "efficiency/speed"?

Comment: I have added some timings. They do depend a bit on the way I have solved the ambiguities in your own question, and on the actual data being tested.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can assert that the symmetric difference between the items of the two dicts are of the three keys:

```
assert {k for k, _ in old_dict.items() ^ updated_dict.items()} == {'status', 'latitude', 'longitude'}
```

Answer (score 3):

A bit of an unorthodox suggestion, but hear me out:

```
differing = {"status", "latitude", "longitude"}
assert all(
    (old_dict[key] != updated_dict[key]) == (key in differing)
    for key in old_dict
)
```

For every `key`, we assert that the values differ if and only if the key is one of the differing keys.

Comment: What if `update_dict` has keys not in `old_dict`? Not clear whether this is relevant for OP.

Comment: I like this approach (assuming keys are indeed the same), but I'd rather use something like `(old_dict[key] == updated_dict[key]) ^ (key in differing)`

Answer (score 2):

You can filter your two dictionaries via a dictionary comprehension and then check for equality:

```
def compare_dicts(d1, d2, exc_keys):
    dct1 = {k: v for k, v in d1.items() if k not in exc_keys}
    dct2 = {k: v for k, v in d2.items() if k not in exc_keys}
    return dct1 == dct2

assert compare_dicts(old_dict, updated_dict, {'status', 'latitude', 'longitude'})
```

Answer (score 1):

I would assume that the full test requires that *exception* or `excluded` dict keys must be different and that the two dictionaries may not have all keys in common.

Some test cases can be written like:

```
import string
import random

random.seed(0)

keys = list(string.ascii_letters)
excluded = 'r', 'm', 'e'

# the original dict
base_dict = {key: random.randint(1, 100) for key in keys}

# some keys, different from excluded are different
unequal_dict = {key: (val if key not in ('q') else random.randint(1, 100)) for key, val in base_dict.items()}

# only the excluded keys are different
equal_dict = {key: (val if key not in excluded else random.randint(1, 100)) for key, val in base_dict.items()}

# only some of the excluded keys are different
partial_dict = {key: (val if key not in excluded[1:] else random.randint(1, 100)) for key, val in base_dict.items()}

# a copy of the base dict
identical_dict = base_dict.copy()

# one more key is added
not_same_keys_dict = base_dict.copy()
not_same_keys_dict['aa'] = 1
```

where now `old_dict` is basically `base_dict`, while `unequal_dict`, `equal_dict`, `partial_dict`, `identical_dict` and `not_same_keys_dict` cover different corner cases.

Then, we define some helper functions to test different inputs at once.

```
def multi_test(func, many_args):
    return [func(*args) for args in many_args]

many_args = (
    (base_dict, unequal_dict, updated),
    (base_dict, equal_dict, updated),
    (base_dict, partial_dict, updated),
    (base_dict, identical_dict, updated),
    (base_dict, not_same_keys_dict, updated))
```

The original code, functionified, looks like:

```
import copy

def dicts_equal_except_orig(dict1, dict2, excluded):
    dict1 = dict1.copy()
    dict2 = dict2.copy()
    result = True
    for key in excluded:
        result = result and (dict1[key] != dict2[key])
        dict1.pop(key)
        dict2.pop(key)
    result = result and (dict1 == dict2)
    return result

print(multi_test(dicts_equal_except_orig, many_args))
# [False, True, False, False, False]

%timeit multi_test(dicts_equal_except_orig, many_args)
# 13.1 µs ± 183 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

And this is just about as fast as you can get with the produced test, under the assumption that the dicts to compare have some keys not in common.
All the other approaches are substantially slower, although potentially cleaner, and could perhaps even be faster in some circumstances, e.g. when the number of keys to exclude is large, etc.
Also, if the `not_same_key` use-case is not needed, i.e. the dicts always have the same keys, then, the `all()`-based solutions will be faster because the will have explicit short-circuiting, and they can be converted by changing:

```
keys = dict1.keys() | dict2.keys()
```

to e.g.

```
keys = dict1.keys()
```

and removing the other sanity checks like `if key in dict1 and key in dict2`.

---

For completeness, I report all the other options I tested:

## my own solution with explicit testing

```
def dicts_equal_except(dict1, dict2, excluded):
    keys = dict1.keys() | dict2.keys()
    return all(
        (dict1[key] != dict2[key] if key in excluded else dict1[key] == dict2[key])
        if key in dict1 and key in dict2 else False
        for key in keys)


print(multi_test(dicts_equal_except, many_args))
# [False, True, False, False, False]

%timeit multi_test(dicts_equal_except, many_args)
# 28.3 µs ± 186 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

## an functionification of @blhsing solution

```
def check_dict_except(dict1, dict2, excluded):
    return {k for k, _ in dict1.items() ^ dict2.items()} == set(excluded)

print(multi_test(check_dict_except, many_args))
# [False, True, False, False, False]

%timeit multi_test(check_dict_except, many_args)
# 30.8 µs ± 498 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

## variants of the solution from @L3viathan

```
def dicts_equal_all(dict1, dict2, excluded):
    keys = dict1.keys() | dict2.keys()
    return all((dict1[key] == dict2[key]) ^ (key in excluded) for key in keys)

print(multi_test(dicts_equal_all, many_args))
# [False, True, False, False, False]

%timeit multi_test(dicts_equal_all, many_args)
# 29.7 µs ± 316 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

and

```
def dicts_equal_all2(dict1, dict2, excluded):
    keys = dict1.keys() | dict2.keys()
    return all((dict1[key] != dict2[key]) == (key in excluded) for key in keys)

print(multi_test(dicts_equal_all2, many_args))
# [False, True, False, False, False]

%timeit multi_test(dicts_equal_all2, many_args)
# 29.9 µs ± 435 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

## an adaptation of @jpp answer:

```
def compare_dicts(dict1, dict2, excluded):
    filter_dict1 = {key: val for key, val in dict1.items() if key not in excluded}
    filter_dict2 = {key: val for key, val in dict2.items() if key not in excluded}
    excluded_dict1 = {key: dict1[key] for key in excluded if key in dict1}
    excluded_dict2 = {key: dict2[key] for key in excluded if key in dict2}
    return filter_dict1 == filter_dict2 and all(dict1[key] != dict2[key] if key in dict1 and key in dict2 else False for key in excluded)

print(multi_test(compare_dicts, many_args))
# [False, True, False, False, False]

%timeit multi_test(compare_dicts, many_args)
# 57.5 µs ± 960 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
old_dict.keys() == updated_dict.keys()
```

it will be true if `old_dict` kyes is a subset of `update_dict` keys.

Comment: That's not what the OP means. `old_dicts` actually have those three keys too, but just with different values, hence the assertions of inequality in the OP's code.

Comment: @blhsingI have updated my answer, thanks for saying.

Answer (score 0):

Several lines, but should be quite fast, because it does not change the structure of the dict pair to be compared.

```
EXC = {"status", "latitude", "longitude"}
saved = {}

for key in EXC:
   saved[key], updated_dict[key] = updated_dict[key], old_dict[key]
cmp = old_dict == updated_dict
for key in EXC:
   old_dict[key], updated_dict[key] = updated_dict[key], saved[key]
```

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
ignore = {'status', 'latitude', 'longitude'}
equal = all([old_value == new[key]
             for key, old_value in old.items()
             if key not in ignore])
```

This iterates over the dict once (I don't think there's a way around that).

Comment: I find this test incomplete, because it assumes both dicts have the same keys. But if they don't, the test may produce a KeyError or a false positive.

Answer (score 0):

there is a library called [deepdiff](https://pypi.org/project/deepdiff/)

```py
from deepdiff import DeepDiff
expected = {'couponCode': '1234', 'usedOnOrder': ['1'], 'usedOnOwners': [], 'sth':{'sth':'sth'}}
actual = {'couponCode': '1234', 'usedOnOrder': ['1'], 'usedOnOwners': [], 'usageCount': 1}
DeepDiff(expected, actual)
```

it will output any differences as a dictionary like this

```
{'dictionary_item_added': [root['usageCount']],
 'dictionary_item_removed': [root['sth']]}
```

you can then drop the fields that you expect before passing in. If the input dicts are the same, it will return an empty dict

here is an example for your case

```py
from deepdiff import DeepDiff
expected = {'status': '1234', 'latitude': ['1'], 'longitude': [], 'sth':{'sth':'sth'}}
actual = {'status': '123', 'latitude': ['2'], 'longitude': [], 'sth':{'sth':'sth'}}
ignored_fields = ['status', 'latitude', 'longitude']


dict_filter = lambda x: {k:v for k,v in x.items() if k not in ignored_fields}

diff = DeepDiff(dict_filter(expected), dict_filter(actual))
assert not diff, diff
```